# Excel Function to Determine Optimal Price

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help creating an Excel function that will determine the optimal price-point for a product, given the required profit margin.

**NET MARGIN** = `(PROFIT / PRICE) = 30%`
**PRICE** = `(COGS + Fixed Costs + Variable Costs)`
**COGS** = `$5.00`
**FIXED** = `$3.00`
**VARIABLE** = `(15% * PRICE)`

The problem that I can't get my head around is that as the price goes up, the variable costs go up as well.  So how do I automate the product pricing for a required margin of 30%?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not an excel question but a math question.

Comment: Shouldn't `PRICE=` be `COST=` ?